# How to configurate ganglia-monitor on a single debian machine?

Tags: debian, configuration, monitoring

[Here](http://195.19.243.13/ganglia/) is what I currently have online,  as you can see there is no information about my debian server.

(While was installing I tried to follow [next instructions](http://phucvdb.blogspot.com/2011/10/monitor-part-2-ganglia.html))

What I have changed in default `gmond.conf`:

```
cluster {
  name = "dspproc"
  owner = "unspecified"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = "dspproc"
}

udp_send_channel {
  mcast_join = 127.0.0.1
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}

udp_recv_channel {
  mcast_join = 127.0.0.1
  port = 8649
  bind = 127.0.0.1
}
```

And this is what I changed in `gmetad.conf`:

```
data_source "dspproc" 10 127.0.0.1
authority "http://195.19.243.13/ganglia/"
trusted_hosts 127.0.0.1 195.19.243.13
case_sensitive_hostnames 0
```

My question is: what I do wrong , and how to make [ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) show info about current machine its installed on?

***Update***
Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34714/12631) Changed to:

```
   udp_send_channel {
      host = 127.0.0.1
      port = 8649
      ttl = 1
    }

    /* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
    udp_recv_channel {
      host = 127.0.0.1 /* line 41 */
      port = 8649
      bind = 127.0.0.1
    }
```

got this on restart:

```
Starting Ganglia Monitor Daemon: /etc/ganglia/gmond.conf:41: no such option 'host'
```

and still `Hosts up:    0` in web ui.

***Upadate 2:***

So... when I read the answer again and went on to the link made next changes into configuration and all worked out!) Thank you [noffle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34714/12631)!

Now that block of gmod.conf looks like

```
    udp_send_channel {
      host = 127.0.0.1
      port = 8649
      ttl = 1
    }

  udp_recv_channel {
    port = 8649
    family = inet4
  }
  udp_recv_channel {
    port = 8649
    family = inet6
  }
```

and all seems to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember having a similar problem when setting up Ganglia many moons ago. This may not be the same issue, but for me it was that my box/network didn't like Ganglia's multicasting. Once I set it up to use unicasting, all was well.

From the [Ganglia docs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/Gmond%203.1.x%20General%20Configuration):

> If only a host and port are specified then gmond will send unicast UDP messages to the hosts specified.

Perhaps try replacing the `mcast_join = 127.0.0.1` with `host = 127.0.0.1`.